# Scrapy dmoz tutorial, no data for desc in csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I followed the dmoz tutorial on Scrapy's official website to scrape the titles, links, and descriptions of Python books and resources. I used exactly the same spider on the tutorial, which reads:

```
import scrapy 
from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

It runs fine and can print the data on the console if I replace yield with print.

But the problem arises when I try to store the scraped data in a csv file using the command: `scrapy dmoz -o items.csv -t csv`. The newly created csv file only have data for title and link, while the column for desc is empty. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: How have you tried debugging this - is the format of the site you're scraping still the same, for example?

Comment: Yes, the format of the site is the same. And I can print the desc in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple issues here.

First of all, the `//ul/li` locator is not the best one in this case since it would also match the top menues and submenues which don't have descriptions.

Also, the descriptions are retrieved with all of the extra whitespaces and newline characters which you need to trim to get the clean results. The most "scrapic" approach would be to use [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with input and output processors.

Complete code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join


class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()


class DmozItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    default_output_processor = Join()

    default_item_class = DmozItem


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li'):
            loader = DmozItemLoader(selector=sel)

            loader.add_xpath('title', 'a/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('link', 'a/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('desc', 'text()')

            yield loader.load_item()
```

After executing

```
$ scrapy runspider myspider.py -o items.csv -t csv
```

here is what I get in `items.csv`:

```
title,link,desc
Core Python Programming,"http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0130260363,00%2Ben-USS_01DBC.html"," - By Wesley J. Chun; Prentice Hall PTR, 2001, ISBN 0130260363. For experienced developers to improve extant skills; professional level examples. Starts by introducing syntax, objects, error handling, functions, classes, built-ins. [Prentice Hall] "
Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Python,http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/html/book.html," - The primary goal of this book is to promote object-oriented design using Python and to illustrate the use of the emerging object-oriented design patterns.
A secondary goal of the book is to present mathematical tools just in time. Analysis techniques and proofs are presented as needed and in the proper context. "
...
Python Programming with the Java Class Libraries: A Tutorial for Building Web and Enterprise Applications with Jython,http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201616165&redir=1," - By Richard Hightower; Addison-Wesley, 2002, 0201616165. Begins with Python basics, many exercises, interactive sessions. Shows programming novices concepts and practical methods. Shows programming experts Python's abilities and ways to interface with Java APIs. [publisher website] "
Python: Visual QuickStart Guide,"http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0201748843,00%2Ben-USS_01DBC.html"," - By Chris Fehily; Peachpit Press, 2002, ISBN 0201748843. Task-based, step-by-step visual reference guide, many screen shots, for courses in digital graphics; Web design, scripting, development; multimedia, page layout, office tools, operating systems. [Prentice Hall] "
Sams Teach Yourself Python in 24 Hours,http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0672317354," - By Ivan Van Laningham; Sams Publishing, 2000, ISBN 0672317354. Split into 24 hands-on, 1 hour lessons; steps needed to learn topic: syntax, language features, OO design and programming, GUIs (Tkinter), system administration, CGI. [Sams Publishing] "
Text Processing in Python,http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/," - By David Mertz; Addison Wesley. Book in progress, full text, ASCII format. Asks for feedback. [author website, Gnosis Software, Inc.] "
XML Processing with Python,http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0130211192," - By Sean McGrath; Prentice Hall PTR, 2000, ISBN 0130211192, has CD-ROM. Methods to build XML applications fast, Python tutorial, DOM and SAX, new Pyxie open source XML processing library. [Prentice Hall PTR] "
```

Comment: alecxe, thank you so your help! I'm not familiarizing myself with Item Loaders. So you think the cause of my problem is that too many white spaces are left in desc and can't be displayed in the csv file?